# Unclear notation in Monk's "Mathematical Logic"

Tags: logic, notation, model-theory

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal A}\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal L}\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$In J. Donald Monk's "Mathematical Logic", the following definition regarding model satisfaction is given: (pp. 196)

> **Definition 11.5** For any formula $\phi$ in $\L$ and any $\L$-structure $\A$, we define $\phi^\A\subseteq \sideset{^\omega}{}A$: for any $x\in\sideset{^\omega}{}A\;(=\{\langle x_i\rangle_{i\in\omega}\mid x_i\in A\})$:
>
> - $x\in(\sigma=\tau)^\A$ iff $\sigma^\A x=\tau^\A x$; (actually, it says $\tau^\A y$, but that seems to be a typo)
> - $(\neg\phi)^A = \sideset{^\omega}{}A\setminus\phi^\A$
> - $\vdots$
> - $x\in(\forall v_i\phi)^\A$ iff for all $a\in A$, $x_a^i\in\phi^A$
>
> If $x\in\phi^\A$, we say $\A\models\phi[x]$.

It is the notation ($x_a^i$) in the last bullet that isn't totally clear to me. From the standard definition of model satisfaction, I would expect something like $$x_a^i = \langle x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},a,x_{i+1},\ldots\rangle$$
However, nowhere in the book I can find the clarification of this notation.

**Question.** Is there someone familiar either with this notation in general, or with Monk's notation in this book in particular, who can give the precise definition of $x_a^i$?

Comment: You are right.. and I cannot find the def in Monk's book. $x\in\sideset{^\omega}{}A$ is a function form $\omega$ to $A$, i.e. a *sequence* $\langle x_i \rangle_{i \in \omega }$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am aware of that definition, that is what I meant by $\ldots$, but I'll make an edit and clarify it by using the $\omega$

Comment: Ah, that would be a possible explanation, I'll work with that

Comment: Ah yes indeed, that seems possible! If you'd want to post this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right; it seems that there is not the definition of this symbol in Monk's book.

$x\in\sideset{^\omega}{}A$ is a function form $ω$ to $A$, i.e. a sequence $⟨x_i⟩_{i∈ω}$.

On page 7 we may find several ways of denoting the value of function $f$ at argument $a$; one of them is $f^a$. Thus, $x^i_a$ must mean that the function $x$ at argument $i$ has value $a$.

Basically, it is what Tarski (Monk was a student of Tarski) defined as $x(k/a)$; see Alfred Tarski & Robert Vaught, [Arithmetical extensions of relational systems](https://eudml.org/doc/88848) (1956), page 83, with the first definition of *satisfiability*.